# Woocommerce tabs text size and colour

Tags: woocommerce, colors, fonts, tabs

I have created two extra tabs in woocommerce product pages, however the text now breaks if you move to a smaller screen, if there away to avoid this, i also need to change the text colour.

http://allabouthome.co.uk/product/butler-style-writing-desk-with-foldable-legs/

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research i managed to use this code to style the tabs, i also removed the reviews tab as not needed and seems to display the text fine now!

```
/* active tabs */
.woocommerce-tabs ul li.active a {
Background-color: #99f7ab;
}
/* inactive tabs */
.woocommerce-tabs ul li a {
Background-color: #70be51;
}
  /* active tabs text */

.woocommerce-tabs ul li.active a {
Color: #60695c !important;

}
  /* active tabs text */
.woocommerce-tabs ul li a {
Color: white !important;

}
```